# Вызов закрытого метода

Tags: java, рефлексия

У меня есть класс и в нем определяется закрытый метод. Задача вызвать этот закрытый метод с использованием рефлексии.

```
class Task12_6{
private void method(){
    System.out.println("В теле метода method()");
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Task12_6 obj = new Task12_6();
Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("method");
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(obj);
```